# pandas Dataframe columns doing algorithm

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    'lon1': [128.0, 135.0, 125.0, 123.0, 136.0],
    'lon2': [128.0, 135.0, 139.0, 142.0, 121.0],
    'lat1': [38.0, 32.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0],
    'lat2': [31.0, 32.0, 35.0, 38.0, 29.0],
    'angle': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})
```

I want to count the angle of each row by this function and save back to the angle column

```
def angle(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2):
    dx = lon2 - lon1
    dy = lat2 - lat1
    direction = 0;
    if ((dx == 0) & (dy == 0)):  # same position
    return direction
    if (dx > 0.0) :    
        direction = 90-np.arctan2(dy,dx)*180/np.pi
    elif (dy > 0.0 ) :    
        direction = 180+(270-(np.arctan2(dy,dx)*180/np.pi))
    else :   
        direction = 360-(270+(np.arctan2(dy,dx)*180/np.pi))
        if (direction < 0) :
            direction += 360

    return (direction.astype(int) % 360)
```

I tried

```
df.ix[df['A'].notnull(), 'angle'] =angle(
    df[df['A'].notnull()]['lon1'],
    df[df['A'].notnull()]['lat1'],
    df[df['A'].notnull()]['lon2'], 
    df[df['A'].notnull()]['lat2'])
```

and I got an error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I tried `for index,row in df.iterrows():` the result of for loop is ok but it took terribly long long time(original data is about 10 million rows )

could anyone kindly give some efficient methods?

Comment: Did you mean for the all the values in the df to be strings or was that a mistake?

Comment: only column['A'] is object others are float

Comment: Vectorize your algorithm: you are thinking about your calculation with a procedural mindset, thus you write a procedure. You have to think in vectors, and instead of writing a function you will get actual code against the dataframe to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to apply function `angle(...)` to every row of your dataframe.

First it is necessary to cast all your string-typed numbers into float so as to calculate.

```
df1.loc[:, "lon1"] = df1.loc[:, "lon1"].astype("float")
df1.loc[:, "lon2"] = df1.loc[:, "lon2"].astype("float")
df1.loc[:, "lat1"] = df1.loc[:, "lat2"].astype("float")
df1.loc[:, "lat2"] = df1.loc[:, "lat2"].astype("float")
```

There you go.

```
df1.loc[:, "angle"] = df1.apply(lambda x: angle(x["lon1"], x["lat1"], x["lon2"], x["lat2"]), axis = 1)
```

As for performance concern, here are some tips for you.

1. Profiling.
2. Use `numba` for JIT compilation and automatic vectorization of your function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more vectorized solution, but here is a solution using the row-wise version of the `apply` method, which only slightly alters your function:

```
def angle(row):
    dx = row.lon2 - row.lon1
    dy = row.lat2 - row.lat1
    direction = 0;
    if ((dx == 0) & (dy == 0)):  # same position
        return direction
    if (dx > 0.0) :    
        direction = 90-np.arctan2(dy,dx)*180/np.pi
    elif (dy > 0.0 ) :    
        direction = 180+(270-(np.arctan2(dy,dx)*180/np.pi))
    else :   
        direction = 360-(270+(np.arctan2(dy,dx)*180/np.pi))
    if (direction < 0) :
        direction += 360

    return (direction.astype(int) % 360)  

df['angle'] = df.apply(angle, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   angle   lat1    lat2    lon1    lon2
0   a   180     38.0    31.0    128.0   128.0
1   a   0       32.0    32.0    135.0   135.0
2   a   102     38.0    35.0    125.0   139.0
3   a   90      38.0    38.0    123.0   142.0
4   a   239     38.0    29.0    136.0   121.0
```